# How to remove files with filenames all in uppercase in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have a directory containing the following files:

`ls`

`ABC BCD CDE DEF abc bcd cde def Abc`

How to remove all the files with filenames all in uppercase? (remove `ABC BCD CDE DEF` in this case)

Comment: Hint: compare `basename` with the output of `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` (can't test right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*[![:upper:]]*' -delete
```

Note that this does not descend into subdirectories and does not delete non-empty directories whose filenames are all in uppercase.

Comment: @Enrico please don't do unnecessary edits on my answers again

Comment: @Enrico ! and ^ are not synonyms, ! is the proper negation operator in bracket expressions in shell's pattern matching notation; ^ might be synonymous in bash or other implementations, but POSIX does not recognize it as a synonym for !. Anyone can look up manuals/standarts and get necessary information from them; I don't have to copy and paste relevant parts to every single answer I posted. And finally, I don't really care about imaginary internet points

Comment: No reason to downvote a good quality answer just because it's not as good as it could be. This being said, bye.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the code will delete _empty_ subdirectories whose names are all uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm ./!(*[![:upper:]]*)
```

This first enables extended globbing patterns in `bash`, and then uses the extended globbing pattern `./!(*[![:upper:]]*)` to match all names in the current directory that does not contain any non-uppercase characters (i.e. only uppercase characters).